# UIControl Touch Down event not working when containing UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

UIView contains UIScrollView which contains all my UITextFields.  When the keyboard shows up, aside from clicking the 'Done' button, I want the keyboard to also disappear when i click somewhere in the view outside the keyboard.  I changed the UIView to UIControl and handles the "Touch Down" event.  Nothing happens.  Is it because it contains a scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is to create a UIButton in interface builder that has an alpha of 0.0f, and covers the entire screen. When you say [textField becomeFirstResponder], say exitButton.hidden = FALSE;

Then create an IBAction linked to the button that closes the keyboard ([textField resignFirstResponder]), and hides the button again.

This way, you have an invisible yet clickable button that obstructs the other views when typing and hides the keyboard when you tap outside the keyboard, without having to mess with touchesBegan.

As a side note, the reason your touches began isn't working is because the touches are only handled when ios determines that your view controller is the lowest view that the touch is in. Since the touch is in your scroll view, the scroll view handles the touches, not your view controller.

Comment: This makes the scrollview not behave normally. Users have to tap twice for normal operation. The first tap makes the button appear. The second tap goes to the scrollview. So this solution is a workaround but defeats the scrollview purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if your textfield is inside scrollview then uncheck delay content touches in inspect property for scroll view. It should work then.